# CI result_array returning : Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1) )

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

My model is this:

```
$parameters=array();

$sql="CALL sp_user_fetch_ids()";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $parameters);
$result=$query->result_array();
$query->next_result();
$query->free_result();
return $result;
```

My controller is this:

```
$data['users']=$this->users_model->ids();
$this->load->view('users',$data);
```

Now `print_r($users)` in view shows:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1) )
```

I can't easily loop with foreach($users as $user) as there are arrays inside arrays. It does work by looping `$users[0], $users[1]...`then further looping for each number. That sounds an overkill and no where in CI documentation is it specified.

The Stored procedure does return only two records with correct columns as I tried with a non-CI script.

Whats happening?

Please keep in mind I want to use PURE ARRAY returned by result_array

Answer (score 0):

When use print_r() function to display array variable in browser, the result will be like this:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2) [1] => Array ( [id] => 1) )

If you copy and run above array using foreach, you will get an error message. Because that is browser display array format.

array ( array ( 'id' => 2), array ( 'id' => 1) )

(OR)

array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 2), 1 => array ( 'id' => 1) )

The above two array methods will return by result_array() function. So you could use foreach to execute your output. It will work.

In Controllers:

store array value into variable,

$data['users'] = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 2), 1 => array ( 'id' => 1) );

OR

$data['users'] = array ( array ( 'id' => 2), array ( 'id' => 1) ) ;

In View execute like this:

foreach ($users as $row){

```
echo $row['id'];
echo "<br>";
```

}